# Error with Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-allocation

I am trying to create a class with an array with a size that is determined at runtime. However, when I try to access the array in the "addToSet" function, I get an "undeclared identifier error". Any help would be appreciated. I am new to C++.

Header File:

```
class ShortestPathSet
{
private:
    //Variables
    int *pathSet;

public:
    //Variables

    int size;


    //Constructor
    ShortestPathSet(int numVertices);

    //Functions
    void addToSet(int vertice, int distance);

};
```

Class File:

```
#include "ShortestPathSet.h"

using namespace std;

ShortestPathSet::ShortestPathSet(int numVertices)   
{
    size = numVertices;
    pathSet = new int[numVertices];
}

void addToSet(int vertice, int distance)
{
    pathSet[vertice] = distance;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the class name here:

```
void addToSet(int vertice, int distance)
```

You meant:

```
void ShortestPathSet::addToSet(int vertice, int distance)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As-is, you're declaring and defining a completely unrelated function, and within the scope of that function there is no such variable `pathSet` - hence undeclared identifier.

Side-note, you probably don't want to make `size` a public member variable.

Comment: So, even when using "namespace std" i still have to include this? Also, thank you so much!!

Comment: @KarlTaht This has nothing to do with `namespace std`. In order to define a class member function outside of the class definition, you need to qualify it with the class name.

Comment: Should I not use a header file for the class then, to simplify things?

Comment: @KarlTaht No, just have to learn the correct syntax for writing your class definitions in a source file.